# Как передать значение в ActionLink написанный внутри js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Есть вот такой `for` по полученным данным:

```
$.getJSON('http://165.179.215.237/auctions', function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('#auctions').append('<tr><td>' + data[i].branch + '</td><td>' + data[i].city +
        '</td><td>' + data[i].state + '</td><td>' + data[i].vehicles_remaining + " of " + data[i].vehicles + " remaining.." + 
        '</td><td>' + data[i].status + '</td><td>' + @Html.ActionLink("connect", "Inventory", "Auctions", new { branchId = data[i].branch_code }, null) + '</td><tr>');
    }
});
```

в строке

```
 @Html.ActionLink("connect", "Inventory", "Auctions", new { branchId = data[i].branch_code }, null)
```

ругается на `data[i].branch_code`

> the name 'data' does not exist in the current context

как мне передать в `actionlink` это значение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#auctions').append('<tr><td>' + data[i].branch + '</td><td>' + data[i].city +
          '</td><td>' + data[i].state + '</td><td>' + data[i].vehicles_remaining + " of " + data[i].vehicles + " remaining.." +
          '</td><td>' + data[i].status + '</td><td>' + '<a href="Inventory/' + data[i].branch_code + '">connect</a>' + '</td><tr>');
        }
```

Сделал без ActionLink